# ChartJs tool tips not showing properly

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I have discovered chart.JS for a while and I wanted to implement it in my website. I wrote the simplest code available on their webpage and the tooltips do appear indeed, but when I use the zoom property on the html tag in my CSS (cause I want to make the whole page smaller) , the tooltips seem to go crazy. Some of them do not appear anymore and others appear only when hovering certain areas of the chart. Is there any fix to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS zoom property is not advised for this use. It is mostly for image zoom, and has very bad support in different browsers. I would advise making content smaller by setting widths of containers, and reducing font sizes.

There is no telling how css zoom will affect the canvas used by ChartJS in different browsers.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: Thank you, it will be a long time consuming process to rewrite every height and width and every font but if that's the only option I will have to do it :(

Comment: Please accept my answer if you found it helpful, and dont need further answers :)